# Event for connection status changing in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is there an event to handle when connection status change?

For example, my app is like `OutLook`. I would like to handle an event to know when there is Internet connection and then to send all pending e-mails.

Now I can check periodically if there is Internet connection, but it seems a poor solution to me. I would to solve it using an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice would be implementing a [background task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx). This way you could send the pending e-mails even if your app is not open any more when the internet connection becomes available.

When registering a background task you can set a trigger and a condition to configure when you want your task to run:

```
var trigger = new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, false);
var condition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);

var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "Send pending e-mails task";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.SendPendingEmailTask";
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
builder.AddCondition(condition);
var task = builder.Register();
```

Your background task must implement the `IBackgroundTask` interface. When the task is triggered, the `Run` method will be called:

```
public sealed class SendPendingEmailTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        // send your e-mails here
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```